# Property to add to Business Central to Discover Kie Execution Server?

Tags: drools, drools-kie-server, drools-kie-workbench

I have installed both Business Central and Kie Execution Server 7.1 on WildFly 14.

Business Central is available at: http://localhost:8080/kie-wb

Kie Execution Server is available at: http://localhost:8080/kie-server

I'm trying to figure out how to deploy one Project designed in the Business Central to the Kie Execution Server. 
I have set the following properties on WildFly:

```
<property name="org.kie.server.controller.user" value="Administrator"/>
<property name="org.kie.server.controller.password" value="Password1!"/>
<property name="org.kie.server.location" value="http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server"/>
<property name="org.kie.server.id" value="demo-server"/>
<property name="org.kie.server.controller" value="http://localhost:8080/kie-wb/rest/controller"/>
```

However, I still have a "No Remote Servers"[image]

And the following WARN in the logs:
10:24:44,212 WARN  `[org.kie.server.services.impl.controller.DefaultRestControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http://localhost:8080/kie-wb/rest/controller/server/demo-server error Error while sending PUT request to http://localhost:8080/kie-wb/rest/controller/server/demo-server response code 401`

What is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 3):

I have solved it. I wrongly deployed also the kie-server-controller.war that was not needed. I've added a short [tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-jbpm/drools/getting-started-with-business-central-workbench) with all the steps in case it could help.

Comment: Where is the issue being explained in your tutorial? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If kie-server and business-central war deployed on same wildfly instance then try adding below properties in system-properties tag

```
   <property name="org.kie.server.user" value="Administrator"/>
   <property name="org.kie.server.pwd" value="Password1!"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however it didn't help. The Controller however works, as I have tested with: curl --user Administrator:Password1! http://localhost:8080/kie-wb/rest/controller/management/servers